# showing div to show action error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can I show a div with information whenever an exception occurs when executing my action?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<div id="dvErrorMsg">
    <a href="#" class="close">[x]</a>
    <p>
        <label id="errorMessage">
        </label>
    </p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("#click_here").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#dvErrorMsg").slideToggle();
            });

            $("#dvErrorMsg a").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#dvErrorMsg").slideUp();
            });
        });
</script>
```

And I have this action in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Validatecall()
{
    //if any exeption happen show div with the custom error
}
```

How can I catch any exception and send the message back in the AJAX response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try returning a JavaScriptResult in this case that will tell your div to expand:

```
public ActionResult Validatecall()
{
    ActionResult result;
    try
    {
       // do whatever
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       result = JavaScript("$('#dvErrorMsg').show();$('#errorMessage').val(/* Put exception message here*/")");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Generally, I would **not** recommend using this way to interact with the view as you now introduce a dependency into the controller on the view itself as explained [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2009/02/07/beware-of-asp-net-mvc-javascriptresult.aspx). I offered it as a way to do it since I do not know exactly how you are calling this action.

Assuming you are calling this action using an ajax call like post I would return a JsonResult indicating if an exception occurred and pass the error message back that way:

```
$.post("urltoaction", function (result) {    
   if (result.success)
   {
      // do whatever
   }
   else
   {
     //exception occurred show errors
     $('#dvErrorMsg').show();
     $('#errorMessage').val(result.exceptionMsg);
   }  
});
```

Here is the controller code now:

```
 public ActionResult Validatecall()
 {
        ActionResult result;
        try
        {
          // do whatever
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           result = new JsonResult()
                    {
                        Data = new { success = false, exceptionMsg = e.Message },
                        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                    };
        }
        return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm calling the action using Html.ActionLink, i want to know how to do using ActionLink. thanks

Comment: @Pedro de La Cruz - Then use the first example in my answer where you return back javascript.

Comment: what about Billy McCafferty suggestion?

Comment: @Pedro de La Cruz - Based on your scenario and what you want to do I would say this is a case where using the JavaScriptResult is ok. Just remember this is a tool to keep in your back pocket and not a go to solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
try { 
  ... whatever
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $('errorMessage').html($e);
}
```

Comment: this is just javascript. the question is about view and controller interaction.

Comment: @nathangonzalez: the question was edited to make sense, before that it was possible the questioner was asking how to handle it in javascript or server side, it was impossible to tell

Comment: @NickLarsen, ah, i see that now. i assumed the edit was just the usual code format. i didn't downvote, but this doesn't answer the current revision of the question at least.

Comment: im calling the view using action link not ajax call!!

Comment: On the server side, i'll leave code to the actual Java people. From an architectural stand point, this might be a good place to use HTTP response codes.  In you server code, send a 200 response code (which is the default behavior) with successes and send a 4xx response code (whatever applies, page doesn't exist, bad call, etc) with your response in json.  Then in the actual call on the javacript side implement a success handler and an error handler.